# Gamecenter Matchmaking - How do I distinguish between player 1 and 2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center

I am beginning to write a game using gamecenter matchmaking. Right now, two players can connect to each other, but I am having trouble figuring out how to distinguish between player 1 and 2. For example, I want player 1 to be able to move player 1 and player 2 to be able to move player 2.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation would be specific to your app so it would be hard to answer more specifically, but basically each person's instance of the app could have an object that is "local player" and an object that is "opponent"... Both of them get to move the "local player" in their local instance, and changes to their "player" are obviously mapped to the "opponent" at the other end.

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply. That helps my understanding of how gamecenter works a little more. I will keep trying to get a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: See [the Game Kit guide about users](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a random number exchance to decide who will be player1 and make the first move.

Generate a random number and store it in a variable.

Send that generated random number to opponent.

Just like this, your opponent sends his own random number to you.

When you receive it, compare with yours.

If yours is greater than his, then you are player1 and he is player2. So you will make the first move.

If yours is lesser than his, then you are player2 and he is player1. So he will make the first move.

If yours and his number are equal (a very rare case) repeat the procedure.

As a reminder, you need to distinguish message types. So use different message type headers. For example:  'R' for random, 'M' for moves.